# Fast way to split an int into bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have an int that fits into 32 bits, what is the fastest way to split it up into four 8-bit values in python? My simple timing test suggests that bit masking and shifting is moderately faster than `divmod()`, but I'm pretty sure I haven't thought of everything.

```
>>> timeit.timeit("x=15774114513484005952; y1, x =divmod(x, 256);y2,x = divmod(x, 256); y3, y4 = divmod(x, 256)")
0.5113952939864248
>>> timeit.timeit("x=15774114513484005952; y1=x&255; x >>= 8;y2=x&255; x>>=8; y3=x&255; y4= x>>8")
0.41230630996869877
```

Before you ask: this operation will be used a lot. I'm using python 3.4.

Comment: Have you tried using the `struct` package for this ?

Comment: Are you asking for additional solutions?

Comment: Also, `15774114513484005952` doesn't fit into 32 bits at all, did you mean 64 bits? Or do you want to ignore the higher bits?

Comment: Side-note: `divmod` is usually a pessimization, even when you actually need both quotient and remainder. In general, `x, y = x // y, x % y` beats `x, y = divmod(x, y)` for all numbers outside the number theory/cryptographic number range, simply because the cost of looking up and calling the `divmod` function is substantially higher than using the dedicated `BINARY_XXX` op codes.

Comment: Sorry for mixing up the example sizes; I'm primarily interested in shorter (32-bit) integers, but was also curious about "long" types (64 bits and beyond).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're doing it a lot, the fastest approach is to create a specialized [`Struct` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.Struct) and pre-bind the `pack` method:

```
# Done once
int_to_four_bytes = struct.Struct('<I').pack  # Little-endian so y1 will be least-significant byte, use '>I' for big-endian

# Done many times (you need to mask here, because your number is >32 bits)
y1, y2, y3, y4 = int_to_four_bytes(x & 0xFFFFFFFF)
```

Using `struct.pack` directly would use a cached `Struct` object after the first use, but you'd pay cache lookup costs to go from format string to cached `Struct` every time, which is suboptimal. By creating and prebinding the `pack` of a `Struct` object (which is implemented in C in CPython), you bypass all Python byte code execution beyond the actual function call, and spend no time on cache lookups. On my machine, this runs in about 205 ns, vs. 267 ns for shift and mask (without reassigning `x`).

An alternate approach (for more general, not `struct` compatible sizes) is using [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes); for example, in this case:

```
y1, y2, y3, y4 = (x & 0xFFFFFFFF).to_bytes(4, 'little')  # Use 'big' for big-endian; on 3.11+, you can omit it entirely, with 'big' being the default
```

which takes about the same amount of time as the manually shifting and masking approach (it took 268 ns per loop), but scales to larger numbers of bytes better.

---

Side-note: Timings are from an older version of CPython. As of 3.11, it appears that `int.to_bytes(4, 'little')` and `int.to_bytes(4)` both run about as fast as the pre-built `struct.Struct.pack`, while `int.to_bytes(4, 'big')` runs a little slower, but still much faster than:

```
y1 = x & 0xFF
y2 = x>>8 & 0xFF
y3 = x>>16 & 0xFF
y4 = x>>24 & 0xFF
```

which takes ~70% longer than the prebound `pack` method, explicit `'little'` `to_bytes` or implicit `'big'` `to_bytes`, and ~50% longer than  explicit `'big'` `to_bytes`. This stuff varies from version to version (the 3.12 self-modifying bytecode might reduce the overhead of the shift-and-mask approach more for instance), so it's not worth getting too hung up on in general. Pre-bound `pack` methods of a `struct.Struct` are reliably no worse than tied for fastest in every version of Python I've tested, with `to_bytes` tied or close behind if you need to handle weirder numbers of bytes, and they're fairly self-documenting, so use one of them.

Comment: I was dubious, so I profiled it: `>>> timeit.timeit("x=15774114513484005952; y1, x =divmod(x, 256);y2,x = divmod(x, 256); y3, y4 = divmod(x, 256)")`: 0.46334090128630123
`>>> timeit.timeit("x=15774114513484005952; y1=x&255; x >>= 8;y2=x&255; x>>=8; y3=x&255; y4= x>>8")`: 0.34517306721051
`>>> timeit.timeit("x=15774114513484005952; ys=P(x&0xffffffff)", "import struct; P=struct.Struct('>I').pack")`: 0.1559582769015151.  It's marginally slower than that if you include the unpacking, but still faster than the alternatives.

Comment: @RoadieRich: Yar. Pre-built `struct`s are actually used internally in [CPython's C code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab3e4be4b539/Objects/memoryobject.c#l1897) because they're hyperoptimized. I was actually comparing to more minimalist shift and mask code that didn't reassign `x`, just did `y1 = x & 0xFF`, `y2 = (x >> 8) & 0xFF`, `y3 = (x >> 16) & 0xFF`, `y4 = (x >> 24) & 0xFF`, which doesn't fare quite as poorly, but even then, the pre-built/bound `Struct.pack` takes 23.2% less time per loop than manual shifting.

Comment: I guess this should have the foot note that results in non-cPython implementations may vary.

Comment: @RoadieRich: Well, that's a footnote for _every_ microoptimization you might make in Python. Unless otherwise specified, the assumption is usually that you're running on CPython. The rules for optimizing Python differ dramatically in different interpreters, and usually, CPython is the most divergent. Most of the other interpreters are either pre-compiled or JIT-ing, and usually see little to no benefit from using standard library functions over writing your own code specialized to the task. Heck, for Cython, the best Cython code is basically C written with Python syntax. :-)

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I knew I was forgetting something :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you need something very fast, you should look into writing a C extension (see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)). You can do this with or without [cython](http://cython.org/).
If you write a lot of these, I definitely recommend looking into cython.

This type of things is exactly what Python is awesome for: you can write your speed critical components in C directly, and it will interact (almost) seamlessly with your python code.

Comment: For this particular case, I'd be surprised if you improved much on a pre-bound `pack` of a pre-built `struct.Struct()` unless the code calling it was also Cythonized or otherwise running in C. If the code performing this operation was also Cythonized, then yes, you could see a gain, but if it's a simple accelerator solely for extracting the bytes, `struct.Struct.pack` is already a C function (as is `int.to_bytes`); at best you'd just specialize it to the case of extracting four bytes from arbitrary sized `int`s (avoiding the need to mask off excess bits). Lot of hassle for tiny gain.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Fortunately speed is not that critical in this case, but it's good to be reminded of the extension option.